# Creating R environments with different dates

Tags: r

Okay this might sound a little crazy but is there a way to create a separate R environment with a different system date? I know that its possible to change the timezone.

Basically, this is what I am trying to do.

```
getSymbols("YHOO",src="google")

#this will give the tail of the most recent data
tail(YHOO)

#create new environment but with a different date
e<-new.env() 

#### line to change system date of new env ####

getSymbols("YHOO",src="google",env=e)

#and this will give the "most recent" data as of the date I set in the environment
tail(get("YHOO",envir = e))
```

I know that there are probably a thousand ways to subset data. I guess what I'm trying to find out is whether there is a way to create "historical" R environments to run functions in.

Update : I realised that I have not been clear (at all) with the question above. The situation is this; I am trying to come out with a trading algorithm. I have a function `foo` which generates a trading indicator based on data from getSymbols.

The problem that I have is that my function logic might have some look ahead bias, i.e. I have been using data that should not have been available to me, and I want to solve this problem.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/lookaheadbias.asp

My proposed solution will compare the output of my function with another output which is ran in a separate environment. As Colin has mentioned, it would be easier to run a loop, subset the data, and rbind it accordingly.

But I am dealing with many xts objects and I am too lazy put a zoom argument in my function, or to rethink my logic. Hence, I'm thinking of a way to automate this and I could easily do the same check with all my future functions.

So I was thinking of running this function in a loop over separate environments with different dates. I am open to any alternative methods which do not involve changing my function as I'm out of ideas here. If there is anyway to "subset" the function and all the data queried and assigned inside it, it would be great.

listenv provides something promising, but there is still the issue of assigning/changing dates in environments.

Comment: No. But I believe you actually want to ask a different question.

Comment: It does sound crazy; we're happy to help address your underlying issue if you try and explicate what it is you're trying to do

Comment: Do you have the date somewhere in your data object? This will be a lot easier if you just filter until a specific date. Any chance you can provide us a data sample?

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I have updated my question